# A way to determine where a URL is being generated?

Tags: 6

I'm a drupal noob, and one of the most frustrating things for me is finding where a specific page is being generated from. The fact that it could be a block, or created via a module, or through a view, I so far can not figure out how I can easily determine where the page is being created.

Is there an easy way of finding the 'culprit' that is generating any given url?

For example: www.example.com/catalog/something

How can I quickly tell what is generating /catalog/something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 6 many different things use the [PathAuto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module to quickly create URL Aliases for your content.

Automatic generation of aliases, the code that controls the administration and application of patterns, the database schema definitions & more can be found within the module.

To answer your original question, it depends on what is creating that alias, a node or view or taxonomy page or whatever, but more times than not pathauto will be involved.

To see the automatic alias settings go to : admin/build/path/pathauto

Comment: And where does one go to see the list of these things?

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Every path in drupal has a registered "system path" that is defined in the menu system. You can get that path at runtime with [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/arg/6).

Comment: `arg()` doesn't return the registered "system path." For example, for example.com/node/1 `arg(0)` returns "node," and `arg(1)` returns "1"; none of them are the registered "system path."

Comment: This is the authortative menu item that drupal recognizes as its "system path". These menu items are defined in hook_menu() which is implemented in every module. Once you find the system path you can just grep for the string in the module if it isnt obvious.

Hint: it is uaually very obvious. The node which might have been urlaliased to /content/my-title would always show node and 1 and that is created by the node module.